SQLite : Appending suffixes to duplicate entries in SQLite table
I am having an issue with appending suffixes to duplicate entries in a SQLite table. Here's the scenario:
I have this table...
id  created_at  updated_at  scene_id
--  ----------  ----------  ---------
1   2024-02-13  2024-03-05  VT-1105
2   2024-02-14  2024-03-06  KA-338
3   2024-02-15  2024-03-07  JU-182
4   2024-02-16  2024-03-08  PX-118
5   2024-02-17  2024-03-09  PO-6339085
6   2024-02-18  2024-03-10  LA-426
7   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338
8   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338
9   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338
10  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182
11  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182
12  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182
13  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182
14  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118
15  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118

...and I'd like to append the duplicate scene names on the bottom rows in SQLite with an A, B, C, etc, like so:
id  created_at  updated_at  scene_id
--  ----------  ----------  ---------
1   2024-02-13  2024-03-05  VT-1105
2   2024-02-14  2024-03-06  KA-338
3   2024-02-15  2024-03-07  JU-182
4   2024-02-16  2024-03-08  PX-118
5   2024-02-17  2024-03-09  PO-6339085
6   2024-02-18  2024-03-10  LA-426
7   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-A
8   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-B
9   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-C
10  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-A
11  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-B
12  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-C
13  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-D
14  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118-A
15  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118-B

I got part way when attempting create a new column with the new names:
SELECT *,
   NULLIF( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id)-1 , 0 ) AS file_no,
   s.scene_id || '-' || CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id )-1) AS new_scene_id
FROM scenes s
ORDER BY s.id ASC

id  created_at  updated_at  scene_id   file_no  new_scene_id
--  ----------  ----------  --------   -------  ------------
1   2024-02-13  2024-03-05  VT-1105     null    VT-1105-@
2   2024-02-14  2024-03-06  KA-338      null    KA-338-@
3   2024-02-15  2024-03-07  JU-182      null    JU-182-@
4   2024-02-16  2024-03-08  PX-118      null    PX-118-@
5   2024-02-17  2024-03-09  PO-6339085  null    PO-6339085-@
6   2024-02-18  2024-03-10  LA-426      null    LA-426-@
7   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338      1       KA-338-A
8   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338      2       KA-338-B
9   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338      3       KA-338-C
10  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182      1       JU-182-A
11  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182      2       JU-182-B
12  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182      3       JU-182-C
13  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182      4       JU-182-D
14  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118      1       PX-118-A
15  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118      2       PX-118-B

I couldn't figure out how to leave the names on the first 6 rows unaltered.  I tried combining CHAR() and NULLIF() on dbfiddle.uk, but it wouldn't run at all if I tried to run CHAR(null).

CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id ) WHEN 1 THEN s.scene_id ELSE s.scene_id || '-' || CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id )-1) END as new_scene_id

That's the ticket, thanks!

Use a CASE statement to decide when to add the suffix
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id)-1  AS file_no,
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id ) 
         WHEN 1 THEN s.scene_id 
         ELSE s.scene_id || '-' || CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id )-1) 
       END as new_scene_id
FROM [scenes] s
ORDER BY s.id ;

Fiddle



id
created_at
updated_at
scene_id
file_no
new_scene_id




1
2024-02-13
2024-03-05
VT-1105
0
VT-1105


2
2024-02-14
2024-03-06
KA-338
0
KA-338


3
2024-02-15
2024-03-07
JU-182
0
JU-182


4
2024-02-16
2024-03-08
PX-118
0
PX-118


5
2024-02-17
2024-03-09
PO-6339085
0
PO-6339085


6
2024-02-18
2024-03-10
LA-426
0
LA-426


7
2024-03-03
2024-03-06
KA-338
1
KA-338-A


8
2024-03-03
2024-03-06
KA-338
2
KA-338-B


9
2024-03-03
2024-03-06
KA-338
3
KA-338-C


10
2024-03-04
2024-03-07
JU-182
1
JU-182-A


11
2024-03-04
2024-03-07
JU-182
2
JU-182-B


12
2024-03-04
2024-03-07
JU-182
3
JU-182-C


13
2024-03-04
2024-03-07
JU-182
4
JU-182-D


14
2024-03-05
2024-03-07
PX-118
1
PX-118-A


15
2024-03-05
2024-03-07
PX-118
2
PX-118-B




Thank you Bart.  I've also incorporated your answer into an UPDATE statement in order to update the original table:
/*------------------------------------------------------
append suffixes to duplicate IDs in scenes table
------------------------------------------------------*/

UPDATE scenes
  SET scene_id = new_scene_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
      s.id AS id,
      CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id) 
        WHEN 1 THEN s.scene_id 
        ELSE s.scene_id || '-' || CHAR(
          64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id)-1
        )
      END as new_scene_id
    FROM scenes s
    ORDER BY s.id ASC
) s2
WHERE s2.id = scenes.id

